# Handling impure DOM manipulation after redux state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an interface that is a list of `<input>`s. Pressing enter in one of the inputs should move focus to the next input, and if you're already on the last input, another one should be added and that one focused. The list of items is managed by redux.

Here's the code to do the pure part of this, without the focusing:

```
class ListItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <li>
        <input 
          defaultValue={this.props.value} 
          onKeyUp={this.onKeyUp.bind(this)} 
          ref={(input) => this.input = input}
        />
      </li>
    );
  }

  onKeyUp(event) {
    this.props.onChange(event.target.value, event.keyCode === 13);
  }

  focus() {
    this.input.focus();
  }
}


class List extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.items.map((item, i) =>
          <ListItem 
            key={i} 
            value={item} 
            onChange={(value, enterPressed) => this.onChange(i, value, enterPressed)}
          />
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }

  onChange(i, value, enterPressed) {
    this.props.dispatch({
      type: 'UPDATE_ITEM',
      index: i,
      value: value
    });
    if (enterPressed && i === this.props.items.length - 1) {
      this.props.dispatch({
        type: 'ADD_ITEM'
      });
    }
  }
}
```

This seems really tricky, because the next list element might not exist yet when we want to focus it, so we somehow need to wait until the redux state change happens, and the list rerenders with the last item.

The only way I can think of to do this is to store an array of refs to each of the list items, then when enter is pressed dispatch the redux event and set the index of the focused list item in component state. Then, in componentDidUpdate (which will get called after the redux state gets updated and the extra input is in the DOM), check state to see which input we should focus, and call the focus method on it.

```
class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.inputs = [];
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.items.map((item, i) =>
          <ListItem 
            key={i} 
            value={item} 
            onChange={(value, enterPressed) => this.onChange(i, value, enterPressed)}
            ref={(input) => this.inputs[i] = input}
          />
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }

  onChange(i, value, enterPressed) {
    this.props.dispatch({
      type: 'UPDATE_ITEM',
      index: i,
      value: value
    });
    if (enterPressed) {
      this.setState({
        inputToFocus: i + 1
      })
      if (i === this.props.items.length - 1) {
        this.props.dispatch({
          type: 'ADD_ITEM'
        });
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (typeof this.state.inputToFocus === 'number') {
      this.inputs[this.state.inputToFocus].focus();
      this.setState({
        inputToFocus: null
      });
    }
  }
```

This feels really fragile and ugly. Is there a better way to do it?

The full example is at https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/59903/.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than focusing programatically and using `state` in your List like you are doing above, you should pass a prop to the ListItem, and the list item themselves can focus themselves if the prop is true. So you could change your actions slightly as well to include the isFocused or not flag, for example:

```
{
  type: 'ADD_ITEM'
  isFocused: true
}

{
  type: 'UPDATE_ITEM',
  index: i,
  value: value,
  isFocused: false/true
}
```

It might seem more work, but using props rather than state will make it easier to test and reason about.

Comment: In what method should the ListItem focus itself? Does the isFocused flag get unset after it does get focused?

Comment: it should be in componentDidMount, as well as componentDidUpdate (they can call a method so you don't duplicate the same code twice), essentially something like, if (this.props.isFocused) this.input.focus.

Comment: You don't need to unset the flag after it is focused, basically let props be the source of truth, you just need to make sure that only 1 ListItem have the isFocused true.

Comment: Unless the flag gets unset, the last focused input will repeatedly get focused whenever the component updates, even if the user has moved focus somewhere else. Once the input is focused once, it should never be forcefully focused again, even if the component updates. I did what you suggested here: https://jsfiddle.net/24mwqot2/1/. Notice how the last forcefully-focused input gets focused whenever you key up in any field.

Comment: let me have a look at your jsfiddle

Comment: i've added an onBlur handler to achieve what you want. https://jsfiddle.net/16g3s5f0/  although this works, it wasn't what i meant originally, rather than having an focused on the same level as items, i actually meant that each item should have a property called isFocused or not - but this solution is also okay depending on how complex your app will be

Comment: If you keep an isFocused for each item, you have to maintain the invariant that only one item is focused at a time. If you just store the index of the focused item, you don't have to worry about it. I thought one of the principles of redux was to keep the state normalized, like you would data in a database. Either way, this solution still seems strained. Is this really the best way?

Comment: you are right about keeping the focused item index stored and not having to worry more about the invariant :)